# No sound on Duke Nukem Forver for PS3

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, duke-nukem-forever

I've started to play DNF on PS3 and installed Patch 1.03. Unfortunatley I don't have any sound on it. It appears to be a common problem on the internet, but I didn't find a solution.

The sound on other games like GT6 is working fine, as well as on the main menu of PS3. But on DNF it's not playing any voice.

Is this a known bug? Is there a known solution or workaround to turn the sounds back on?